# Save xlsl file with Hebrew as txt to load into Photoshop data sets

Tags: excel, character-encoding, photoshop, txt, hebrew

I have an Excel (xlsx) file that has 3 columns of data that is set to replace said data in a Photoshop file (PSD), to do so I need to load it into Photoshop in a txt format, encoded to ANSI, so that Photoshop can read that file, and export it a bunch of times each time with the next row's properties.

However my Excel file has some Hebrew text, that is lost when encoding to ANSI, I tried other encodings but Photoshop doesn't accept them, how can I still feed Photoshop with the Hebrew data? (It's a lot of photos so I can't do it manually one by one)

Comment: Can you not save out the txt files as UTF-8?

Comment: I can, but then Photoshop can't read the file.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: I've got a simple text file, with some Hebrew text on it.

And from Photoshop:

```
var myfile = "D:\\temp\\hebrew.txt"; // change this


var text = read_it(myfile);

alert(text); 
// השועל החום המהיר קופץ מעל הכלב העצלן.


// function READ IT (filename with path) :returns string
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
function read_it(afilepath)
{
    var theFile = new File(afilepath);

    //read in file 
    var words = ""; // text collection string
    var theTextFile = new File(theFile);
    theTextFile.open('r');

    while(!theTextFile.eof)
    {
      var line = theTextFile.readln();
      if (line != null && line.length >0)
      {
        words += line + "\n";
      }
 
    }
    theTextFile.close();

    // return string
    return words;
}
```